# Ember.js component rerender not rerendering

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to render some data into a table. The data is organized by years, and users can add years to the index.

When the user adds a year, the data for that year is loaded via AJAX and added to an `Ember.Object` `info`, like this:

```
var self=this;
Ember.$.getJSON('url'+year, function(data) {
  var info = self.get("info");
  info['total'][year] = data.total;
  info['commission'][year] = data.commission;
}
```

In the template, the data is shown via `each-in` helpers:

```
{{#each-in info.total as |k t|}}
  {{t}}
{{/each-in}}
```

Following the manual, [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/#toc_re-rendering), since `each-in` is not bound to new properties, I added `self.rerender();` after the ajax assigments in the component.

My issue is that the component is NOT rerendering. If I change routes and come back, the page is rerendered and the data shows, so the issue is clearly on the rerender() call.

PS: The code shown here is a simplified example; there is a reason why I must use `each-in` and any solution that necessitates changing the data structure won't help. I just need to know why `rerender()` is not rerendering and how to make it do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since glimmer 2 you don't need to call `rerender` for an `each-in` loop.

Now you could create new objects, however a faster solution is to just use `Ember.set` instead of the `[]` syntax. So replace this:

```
info['total'][year] = data.total;
```

with this:

```
Ember.set(info, `total.${year}`, data.total);
```

And it will work.

If you refuse to do that you should call `notifyPropertyChange`. However `Ember.set` is preferred.

Checkout [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f11cf8074bb0f9eac3727667b009d142?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs).

Comment: `Ember.set(this.get('info.total'), year, data.total);`

Comment: I would recommend ``Ember.set(this, `info.total.${year}`, data.total);``, but yep. thats the way.

Answer (score 2):

What is your Ember version? The guide you had provided is for 2.6.0, and yet the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/881a39bbd9708f7004ed1ad838f31705?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) that works at Ember 2.6.0 seems to be working. However; after Glimmer 2 introduction (I mean since release 2.10.0) this does not seem to be working. As you can see in the guide of [2.10.0](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/#toc_re-rendering), the part explaining re-rendering is removed. Hence, it means you can no longer achieve what you want the same way.

If using `each-in` helper is a must for you; you can check the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e852c425689b8588248dc08cd88e80b5?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2C) that runs at Ember 2.12.0 and still works. Instead of forcing re-rendering via `self.rerender` within component; you can just rely on Ember's `set` just like Lux stated. I updated twiddle to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot to check versions.

Comment: no problem at all! that happens to me as well sometimes ;)